# open and read zip file from chrome-app

Tags: google-chrome-app

Now that google chrome handles zip files, basically, is there a way from inside a chrome app to get the files, and the contents of the files in a zip archive?   From the user end, a zip file is mounted as a drive, containing the contents, but from the app end, the zip file is just a file. Is there a way from the app to "mount" the file, get the mount point and enumerate the contents and inflate them?

Comment: Nothing stops you from implementing this yourself - you can get the read access for the zip file, decompress it in your JavaScript and inflate files to a temporary HTML Filesystem. What is your question, exactly? Whether there is specific API to do that?

Comment: Yes, I don't want to integrare JSZip, etc, since chrome has the capabilities built in already, I just don't see how I can access it from an extension/app

Answer (score 1):

Nope, there are no particular APIs exposed that would allow this.

You will need to include your own ZIP engine - be it in JavaScript or in (P)NaCl. Then you can work with HTML Filesystem to hold inflated files while you work with them.

Comment: thanks, I found [JSZip](https://stuk.github.io/jszip/) to be an excellent easy to use helper

Comment: PNaCl can potentially be much faster / use less resources than JS-based solutions.